# How to handle boost.python argument error?

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I have a python extension function

```
static void EXTrender_effect(EffectGlobals_t *effect_handle, 
                    std::string preset,
            bp::object dest, int xdim, int ydim)
{ ... }
```

that I export as usual in my boost.python extension:

```
def("render_effect", EXTrender_effect);
```

When I call that from python(2.7), I get a C++ exception `boost::python::error_already_set`.  Tracing that down in Visual Studio, I can see it's coming from a `boost::python::objects::function::argument_error`.  So OK, I have an argument error; I'm probably calling it with the wrong args.  What I'd like to do is print or throw something sensible in my python extension when this happens, so users of my extension will see the nice message that I know is lurking in `PyErr_Fetch`.  (I can see the message getting built in the boost.python argument_error code.)

But I can't catch that `error_already_set`; boost.python does that internally around the funcall. And I can't check for python errors in my extension code, since my function never gets called (the argument error is detected by boost.python).  What ends up happening is it just silently fails.

What can I hook up so I (or my users) can see the argument error messages?  And ideally convert those into python exceptions?

This is all Win7, Python2.7.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problem?  For example, what information is missing from raised `Boost.Python.ArgumentError` exception?

Comment: I don't get any exception at all at the python level.  The C++ exception appears to be swallowed up somewhere in the boost.python C->python interface, and I don't see it generating a python exception from that.  I could be missing something however, or maybe my python code (which is complex) is suppressing the python exception or something.

Comment: When an exception occurs, Boost.Python should be properly raising a Python exception.  Per the [error](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/errors.html) documentation, Boost.Python will perform exception translation for C++ functions wrapped by `make_function()`, `make_constructor()`, `def()` or `class_::def()`.  Maybe consider trying to duplicate the problem in an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: After playing with it some more, I now suspect PyQt is the real culprit; it seems to somehow eat exceptions silently.  I can't reproduce it in a non-PyQt example.